# Angular Select - Alternative to using $Scope.Watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS drop down using the angular-select2 directive in an existing project. The pattern that is used in the current code base is to monitor the model for the select using a watch. The problem is that this only works and is only fired when the value changes.

This is problematic if the user selects the same option twice - I need to fire this change regardless of if the value has changed or not; in other words on click:

This is how we currently do it:

```
      $scope.$watch('myConfig.myField', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                        addContent(data);
                    }
                );
        });
```

The obvious solution is to use an ng-click, but I don't have access to the control/directive or sub items; this is how the DDL is declared:

```
   <div my-dropdown="MyConfigObject" ng-model="SearchRequest.SomeModelValue"></div>
```

So for example, if this drop down contains one item, each time I click that item I need to fire an event to capture and handle that click.

There should be an easy and elegant angular way of doing this but it escapes me. Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried ng-change?

Comment: Yes, I added ng-change and it does not hit the function: <div ng-change="addMsgTest()" my-dropdown="myDropdownConfig"> and in the controller: $scope.addMsgTest = function () { }; <== this does not get hit when I select options.

Comment: Can you set up a small example in Plunker?